# Classifier from Two Distributions

Tags: probability-or-statistics, machine-learning

Maybe this is a noob question and maybe it should be on CrossValidated ...

Suppose I have two classes {class1, class2} and have their two associated EmpiricalDistribution[]s, pdf1(x) and pdf2(x).

Then, given an x value, what is the appropriate way to classify x (i.e. calculate the probability of each class) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dist1 = EmpiricalDistribution[Range[11] -> Range[1, 0, -.1]];
dist2 = EmpiricalDistribution[Range[11] -> Range[0, 1, .1]];
```

```
DiscretePlot[PDF[dist1, x], {x, 0, 1, .1}]
```

[image]

```
DiscretePlot[PDF[dist2, x], {x, 0, 1, .1}]
```

[image]

```
With[{x = 0.3}, {#1, #2}/(#1 + #2) & @@ {PDF[dist1, x], PDF[dist2, x]}]
```

> (* class1_prob, class2_prob *)
>
> {0.666667, 0.333333}

Comment: sure, but is this really the correct answer ?

Comment: @AbelBrown Why not?